# python file build to exe always OSError: cannot open resource

Tags: python

my code work well if this source `PY` or `ipynb` but getting error when im convert it to `exe` file use `PyInstaller`, here my full code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from barcode import Code128
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

class BarcodeGeneratorApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Barcode Generator")

        self.label_numbers = tk.Label(self.master, text="Barcode:")
        self.label_numbers.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)

        self.entry_numbers = tk.Entry(self.master)
        self.entry_numbers.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)

        self.generate_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Generate Barcodes", command=self.generate_barcodes)
        self.generate_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

    def generate_barcodes(self):
        numbers = self.entry_numbers.get().split(',')

        folder_path = filedialog.askdirectory()

        for number in numbers:
            number = number.strip()
            if number:
                pdf_filename = f"{folder_path}/barcode_{number}_code128.pdf"
                self.generate_and_save_barcode_to_pdf(pdf_filename, number)

        messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Barcodes generated successfully.")

    def generate_and_save_barcode_to_pdf(self, pdf_filename, number):
        c = canvas.Canvas(pdf_filename, pagesize=letter)
        my_code = Code128(number, writer=ImageWriter())
        barcode_image = my_code.render()
        c.drawInlineImage(barcode_image, 100, 500, width=200, height=100)
        c.save()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = BarcodeGeneratorApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

when generate to exe the error show

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
  File "Fack.py", line 31, in generate_barcodes
  File "Fack.py", line 38, in generate_and_save_barcode_to_pdf
  File "barcode\codex.py", line 255, in render
  File "barcode\base.py", line 100, in render
  File "barcode\writer.py", line 269, in render
  File "barcode\writer.py", line 440, in _paint_text
  File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 791, in truetype
  File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 788, in freetype
  File "PIL\ImageFont.py", line 226, in __init__
OSError: cannot open resource
```

Comment: I'm guessing that there's something wrong with ```barcode_image``` though I find that Traceback a little weird without the actual code mentioned.

Comment: yess, im confused too, any advice?

Comment: im already use `folder_path = "C:/Code"       font_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "arial.ttf")`

Comment: I tried your script locally and it works.  What version of python-barcode, and reportlab are you using?

Comment: yess run normal if this file format py and ipynb, but when convert it to exe use PyInstaller or Py2Exe will get that error cannot open resoure, im use 3.11.6 Py,  barcode-1.0.3, and use VCS 1.84.2

Comment: im use reportlab 4.0.7 @ewokx